# dynamically adding a resource to a python coap server with coapthon library

Tags: python, coap

I am trying to build a coap server, in which I can add a new resource without the need to stop the server, recode it and restart .my server is suppossed to host two types of resources, "sensors(Sens-Me)" and "Actuators(Act-Me)" . I want that if I press the A key, a new instance of actuator should be added to the server, likewise If i Press S for Sensor .Below is my code :

```
from coapthon.resources.resource import Resource
from coapthon.server.coap import CoAP


class Sensor(Resource):

   def __init__(self,name="Sensor",coap_server=None):
    super(Sensor,self).__init__(name,coap_server,visible=True,observable=True,allow_children=True)
    self.payload = "This is a new sensor"
    self.resource_type = "rt1"
    self.content_type = "application/json"
    self.interface_type = "if1"
    self.var = 0

   def render_GET(self,request):
       self.payload = "new sensor value ::{}".format(str(int(self.var+1)))
       self.var +=1
   return self

class Actuator(Resource):
def __init__(self,name="Actuator",coap_server=None):
   super(Actuator,self).__init__(name,coap_server,visible=True,observable=True)
   self.payload="This is an actuator"
   self.resource_type="rt1"
def render_GET(self,request):
   return self

class CoAPServer(CoAP):
  def __init__(self, host, port, multicast=False):
    CoAP.__init__(self,(host,port),multicast)
        self.add_resource('sens-Me/',Sensor())
        self.add_resource('act-Me/',Actuator())
    print "CoAP server started on {}:{}".format(str(host),str(port))
    print self.root.dump()


def main():
  ip = "0.0.0.0"
  port = 5683
  multicast=False
  server = CoAPServer(ip,port,multicast)
  try:
    server.listen(10)
            print "executed after listen"
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
 main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly do you want to do.
Is it just to replace a resource on the same route or add a new one?

## Replace a resource

It is not possible according to the current **coapthon** version source:

https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon/blob/b6983fbf48399bc5687656be55ac5b9cce4f4718/coapthon/server/coap.py#L279

```
 try:
    res = self.root[actual_path]
 except KeyError:
   res = None
 if res is None:
   if len(paths) != i:
       return False
   resource.path = actual_path
       self.root[actual_path] = resource
```

Alternatively, you can solve it in scope of request.
Say, have a registry of handlers which are used by resources and can be changed on a user input event. Well, you'll not be able to add new routes.

If you absolutely need that feature, you may request it from a developer or contribute to that project.

## Add a new resource

I have extended your snippet a little bit.
I have a little experience in Python so I an not sure I've made everything properly, but it works.
There is a separate thread polling the user input and adding the same resource. Add the needed code there.

```
from coapthon.resources.resource import Resource
from coapthon.server.coap import CoAP
from threading import Thread
import sys

class Sensor(Resource):
  def __init__(self,name="Sensor",coap_server=None):
    super(Sensor,self).__init__(name,coap_server,visible=True,observable=True,allow_children=True)
    self.payload = "This is a new sensor"
    self.resource_type = "rt1"
    self.content_type = "application/json"
    self.interface_type = "if1"
    self.var = 0

  def render_GET(self,request):
    self.payload = "new sensor value ::{}".format(str(int(self.var+1)))
    self.var +=1
    return self

class Actuator(Resource):
  def __init__(self,name="Actuator",coap_server=None):
    super(Actuator,self).__init__(name,coap_server,visible=True,observable=True)
    self.payload="This is an actuator"
    self.resource_type="rt1"
  def render_GET(self,request):
    return self

class CoAPServer(CoAP):
  def __init__(self, host, port, multicast=False):
    CoAP.__init__(self,(host,port),multicast)
    self.add_resource('sens-Me/',Sensor())
    self.add_resource('act-Me/',Actuator())
    print "CoAP server started on {}:{}".format(str(host),str(port))
    print self.root.dump()

def pollUserInput(server):
  while 1:
    user_input = raw_input("Some input please: ")
    print user_input
    server.add_resource('sens-Me2/', Sensor())

def main():
  ip = "0.0.0.0"
  port = 5683
  multicast=False

  server = CoAPServer(ip,port,multicast)
  thread = Thread(target = pollUserInput, args=(server,))
  thread.setDaemon(True)
  thread.start()

  try:
    server.listen(10)
    print "executed after listen"
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print server.root.dump()
    server.close()
    sys.exit()

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your modification(Add a resource) is what i wanted, i will make further changes to it, to get exactly what I need .